# Git push heroku master error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have successfully created using `heroku create` but when i push from git it gives me error as below:-

```
C:\Sites\boot>git push heroku master

!  Your account snehp92@gmail.com does not have access to protected-thicket-253
8.
!
!  SSH Key Fingerprint: 6e:d8:39:da:45:ad:b5:b2:e5:36:2e:14:0e:92:b5:8e

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Give the result of running: **git remote -v**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your ssh key to heroku. To add your keys run the following command

```
heroku keys:add
```

If you don't have a key then generate a new key with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and then add the ssh key to heroku

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the latest version of [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), and then adding the repository again:

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: adam@example.com
Password:
Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn]
Generating new SSH public key.
Uploading ssh public key /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

git remote -v
git remove heroku master

heroku git:remote -a protected-thicket-253
```